# Alternative way to run wav2letter Facebook AI Research Speech to Text model on Windows Machine

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I'm trying to implement Speech-to-text using wav2letter. As far as I have researched the model uses the Arrayfire tensor library with dependency on flashlight ML library.

Now, the flashlight library is built for Linux based system.

Is there any way to run this model on the Windows-based system.

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of whether or not you're trying to train or run the inference pipeline, you have two options besides trying to get everything to build from source from MSVC (which isn't currently supported).

1. Use the [provided CUDA Dockerfile](https://github.com/facebookresearch/wav2letter/blob/master/Dockerfile-CUDA) to create and build everything. You should be able to use GPUs connected to the machine through Docker. There's also now a [new Dockerfile for inference](https://github.com/facebookresearch/wav2letter/blob/master/Dockerfile-Inference) that should run on your machine and doesn't include many other dependencies.
2. Build everything in the Linux subsystem on your Windows machine if you're able. The inference pipeline should work there at the very least.

Answer (score 1):

`Wav2Letter` has different train- and inference-time dependencies.

I am assuming you will be performing training on CUDA backend. If so, you need `ArrayFire` and `Flashlight`.

For inference, besides basic dependancies (such as `cereal` for serialization, etc.) you don't need either. The FAIR team has provided their own implementations of neural network layers (linear, conv1d, etc.) based on FBGEMM (FB General Matrix Multiplication) backend. FBGEMM can both be compiled for CPU and CUDA backend - on intel-based CPUs, it can further be accelerated using intel's optimized MKL math library and on CUDA backend, using cuDNN.

You are free to add your own implementations of backend based on say, LibTorch or C++ TensorFlow and submit a PR.